# Angular 9 - Landing Page Routing [Trivial]

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a simple angular project, with two components (app and room). The app component acts as a landing page. It contains a fullscreen video with one button that should redirect to the room component. Since the website doesn't contain a header-menu, I'm not sure how to best implement routing. My first idea was, to hide the landing page with **ngIf** whenever im on the room component, but that can't be the best approach. I would be grateful for better suggestions.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RoomComponent } from './room/room.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'room', component: RoomComponent },
  { path: '', component: AppComponent},
  { path: '**', component: AppComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RoomComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    )
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should move your landing page in a separate component, for example, a component named **landing** and match this new component to the default **route ''**;

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'room', 
    component: RoomComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: LandingComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { 
    path: '**', 
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];
```

Your app.component.html should only keep the global layout (nav menu if you have, main content and eventually footer) and the most important, **the router-outlet**.

```
<!-- App component should contains application layout -->

<nav class="app-menu">
  <!-- Your app menu should go here. Will be visible on each application "page" -->
</nav>

<main class="app-content">
  <!-- Only router outlet to insert component as main content when route change -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>

<footer>
  <!-- Your app footer should go there. Will be visible on each application "page" -->
</footer>
```

Then, on you landing page, use a router-link on your button that target '/room'. When user will click on the button, the route will change to /room and the router will load the RoomComponent (that matches the /room route) and insert it in the router-oulet in place of the previous LandingComponent.

```
<p>
landing works!
</p>
<button [routerLink]="['/room']">Go to room</button>
```

This way, you don't need to hide your landing page anymore, the router and router-outlet mechanism provided by Angular will manage it for you.

I have made a stackbliz exemple for you if you want to try : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3moc8g]

Comment: Stackblitz broken... ;)